# barman + barman can show the details from backup directory

Tags: backup, restore, linux, barman

we have linux machine as backup server with barman tool

when I want to see the details backup with the command barman show-backup

then I get the following exceptions

```
# barman show-backup main-db-server 20170717T122533
  Backup 20170717T122533:
  Server Name            : main-db-server
  Status                 : STARTED
  EXCEPTION: 'children_timelines'
  See log file for more details.
```

example of my backup folder on my backup server:

```
# ls -l /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/base
  total 0
  drwxr-xr-x 3 barman barman 35 Jul 17 11:23 20170717T112317
  drwxr-xr-x 3 barman barman 35 Jul 17 11:30 20170717T113012
  drwxr-xr-x 3 barman barman 35 Jul 17 11:35 20170717T113536
  .
  .
```

please advice what is the error about children_timelines sand how to fix it in order to restore the backup on DB server

Answer (score 0):

that's been fixed in the latest 2.2 release.

This is the actual fix: https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman/commit/e0d2e9044c1d3c4bf234024f90b6836cb0846ca4